# Couchbase Lite how to get data from Cluster without sync it to local database

Tags: ios, synchronization, couchbase, gateway

I'm building a social network, and want to use Couchbase as backend, but if I'll use sync gateway after sometime I'll have a lot of data on device that user doesn't need to use.

How I can get/post/put info to Couchbase Server without sync function or how I can clear local database without deleting information from server?

Comment: It seems like this a problem for all developers who is using Couchbase Lite ;)

Comment: I'll share solution soon. I found few ways to do that, I'll check them and then post there an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a 100% working solution, but want to share some information that I've got from community and representatives of Couchbase London & California.

First of all you can use CouchCocoa for working directly with SyncGateway, but it doesn't work as you expects, some part of your needs you can resolve using CouchCocoa.

Another way to build your own API proxy, but when you're a mobile developer only, it isn't a great idea. But, it could be created on different languages.

And as the last one thing is using Purge function. There are links to documentation that Couchbase team have now: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Purge_Documents and http://couchbase.github.io/couchbase-lite-ios/docs/html/interfaceCBLDocument.html#a06bf7fd41678953924a56f76a921fe5a

Also you can go to Google Group and see all issues and how to fix/resolve/find workaround. Also, from our discussion with Couchbase representatives there will be a thread about how to get rid of synced info and so on. Link to Google Group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mobile-couchbase.

if you have any question, ask me, I'll try to help in the information area that I've already discovered.

Comment: Join Couchbase Google Group that is about purge and sync problem that we've experience now. Lets together help each other to find the best way to solve the issue. Link to Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobile-couchbase/UcFI5MIz4tg